# Finding invariant closed subspace which are also subgroups for the action of $\text{SL}(2, \Bbb Z)$ on $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions

I recently came across to the following action of $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ on the space $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ defined as
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \big(v,\,w\big)\mapsto \big(dv-cw,\,-bv+aw\big)=\big(v,\,w\big)
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$ where $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n),\, w=(w_1,\dots,w_n)\in \Bbb R^n$.

I would like to determine the $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$-invariant closed subsets.

**Some examples**

Of course the trivial subspaces $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ are among these. One can easily check that every linear subspace of the form $V\times V$, where $V<\Bbb R^n$ is invariant under these action. On the other hand, if $V,W<\Bbb R^n$ are different subspaces, then $V\times W$ is not invariant.
Similarly, if $\Lambda$ is any lattice in $\Bbb R^n$, then $\Lambda\times\Lambda$ is also invariant.

Not only, considering $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ as $\Bbb R^2\times\cdots\times\Bbb R^2$, where $\big(v,\,w\big)$ is identified with $\big(\big(v_1,\,w_1\big),\dots,\big(v_n,\,w_n\big)\big)$, if $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\Bbb R^2$, the $n$-times product $\Lambda\times\cdots\times\Lambda$ is $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$-invariant.

These are some examples of invariant closed subspaces I have found so far. I would like to determine all of them. Any idea, hint or reference is very appreciated!

**Edit:** I was thinking this problem from a generic point of view. However, I am mainly interested on invariant closed subset of $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ which are also subgroups.

Comment: It's not an unusual action. First since this is the restriction of an algebraic action of $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ in which it's Zariski dense, its invariant subspaces are the same as for the $G$-action and since $G$ is semisimple this behaves well. Also this action, call it $W_n$, obviously splits coordinate-wise as $W_1^{\otimes n}$, and $W_1$ is absolutely irreducible. Describing invariant subspaces is then an exercise.

Comment: Hi @YCor, thanks for the answer first. I have a couple of doubts. Why do you say that the invariant subspaces for the $\text{SL}(2\Bbb Z)$ action are the same as for the $G$-action? The $n$-times product of lattice is not $G$-invariant. Am I missing something? The second doubt is about the splitting, the action is diagonal on $\Bbb R^2\times\cdots\times \Bbb R^2$. So the splitting may contain factors greater than $W_1$.

Comment: When you say "subspace", what exactly do you mean? Presumably not vector subspace (because you mention lattices) - that was probably the context of the answer of @YCor . So what is it? Subset ? Algebraic subvariety?

Comment: Yes, maybe the term "subspace" has been misleading. I actually mean topological subspaces, where $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n$ is endowed with the product of the standard euclidean topology. The point Is that I have examples with linear subspaces and lattices.

Comment: Topological subspace just means any subset (with the endowed topology, but this is irrelevant to the question). You really want no further assumption such as "closed"?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in closed subspaces in particular. Right, I forgot to write it.

Comment: Have you looked at the case $n=1$? It's already non-trivial. In general, the question is  equivalent to describe closed subsets of the (usually non-Hausdorff) quotient space.

Comment: I did. In that case we have the action on $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\cong\Bbb R^2$. So there are lattices of course. If you take a vector $v\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $v$ is not a multiple of an integral vector (all entries are integers) then the orbit is dense in $\Bbb R^2$. If the entries are rational multiples of integers, instead, the orbit is discrete.

Comment: Once $n\ge 3$ (maybe even $2$), this is hopeless since the action has nonempty domain of proper discontinuity.